# -bash: cd: supbot-tut: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, python-3.x, terminal

I opened terminal fresh and typed.

```
$ python3
```

Then I typed quit to get out of it.

```
$ quit()
```

I then typed:

```
$ pip3 install splinter requests bs4
```

After I typed:

```
$ cd supbot-tut
-bash: cd: supbot-tut: No such file or directory
```

When I typed that I got the error code: -bash: cd: supbot-tut: No such file or directory.

I tried this dozens of times and it won't work. I do not know how to fix this problem and I am a new coder so please send exact code I have to write to fix this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you're in the correct directory using `pwd` and see if that directory contains `supbot-tut` that you're trying to get into with `ls`.

Or you can make a directory using `mkdir supbot-tut` then you will be able to `cd` into it.

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when you try to issue the **cd** command and you pass a directory (a folder) that doesn't exist. Can you type the command **ls** and see if you see that directory listed. You can easily check with your file explorer too.  Create that directory and your issue should go away.